# 2008 Renault Laguna - Location of EPB Fuse?

Tags: laguna

Car is a Laguna 1.6cc 2008 estate.

I cant find the 25A white fuse for the Electronic Parking Brake (EPB) - have looked under the passenger seat and there is no fuse box there. Where is this fuse located?

Answer (score 1):

Interior fuse box on these is on the left hand side of the dash - if you've got a Right Hand Drive model open the glovebox and there should be a cover you can pop open on the left hand side. There should be a diagram showing which fuse is which as well.

If you have a Left Hand Drive model then under the steering column you should be able to hinge open the left hand side of the dash and the fuse box is behind that.